# Intellij complains about fork mode when running tests with code cover

Tags: testing, configuration, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I want to get information about how much the tests cover in our application. When I try to run all tests with coverage Intellij complains about the current fork mode. See image below.

[image]

The strange thing is that in the selected Run/Debug Configuration that I have the Fork mode is already set to none. Intellij still encourage me to change the Fork mode to none.

[image]

I am using Intellij 13.0.1, this is a feature that have been around for long, so I am missing something obvious, right?

Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Comment: I'd suggest opening a ticket at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/dashboard, they're usually very responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IDEA-118572 unable to run JUnit tests with code coverage - fork mode is required](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118572)

Comment: Thanks, when reading that ticket and after some testing I learned that codecoverage with working directory $MODULE_DIR$ and "Search for test: In whole project" is the reason behind the problem.

When removing $MODULE_DIR$ it worked. Unfortunetly I need $MODULE_DIR$, therefore I need to make a configuration for each module.